# How to align Text to a Label's text instead of it's image in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

If I have a Label that uses a system image and some text, let's call the text "title". How would I align the subtitle to the the leading edge of the title text and not the image?

[image: example]

This seems to work, but is there another way? Something just seems off about setting the top alignment.

```swift
HStack(alignment: .top) {
    Image(systemName: "gift")
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      Text("Title")
      Text("Subtitle")
    }
}
```

[image: Working]

Comment: I don't think you can, try using a standard HStack instead.

Comment: Never use Label for this kind of work, use Text and Image, it is better and safer to maintain. label is kinda privilege

Comment: Your solution is better. :)